# superior/inferior key is missing on my keyboard

Tags: keyboard, key

I recently bought a DELL Latitude E6410 and can't found (tried everything) the "[diple](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevron_%28typographie%29#Usage_informatique)" key .
Here is a photo of my keyboard : http://www.touchedeclavier.com/3357-thickbox_default/dell-latitude-e6410.jpg

I'm running debian 8 . 
Is there a solution to assign both diple symbols to another key ?

Thank you in advance,